# OpenCV segfault with SIFT detector in Python

Tags: python, sift, opencv

[image: small image]

```py
import cv2

img1 = cv2.imread('imref/ref-DN.png',0)    # queryImage


# Initiate SIFT detector
sift = cv2.SIFT()

# find the keypoints and descriptors with SIFT
kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)

print("end")
```

output it , en :

```
Errore di segmentazione (core dump creato)
Segmentation error (core dump created)
```

My Linux Kubuntu 18.04LTS desktop has 32GB of RAM

Other codes  works fine but not SIFT

```
cat /proc/meminfo 

MemTotal:       32776404 kB
MemFree:        29683128 kB
MemAvailable:   31038428 kB
```

the image attached here is 2k  (61x54)pixel

Why this appens? Thanks all

`cv2.__version__` ->  '4.5.1'

Thanks to alkasm

```py
sift = cv2.SIFT_create()
```

solved my problem

Comment: Can you try with `sift = cv2.SIFT_create()`? And what version of OpenCV are you using?

Comment: Nice .. no more core dump . thanks !

Comment: cv2.__version__ ->  '4.5.1'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feature detectors in OpenCV should be created using their static `create` methods. It isn't explicit in the API reference to not use the constructors, but you can see in the [docs for the `SIFT` class](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d7/d60/classcv_1_1SIFT.html) that the `create()` methods are the only ones shown (and they show that the corresponding Python call is `SIFT_create()`).

The reason this is necessary is because the OpenCV `Algorithm` class (which `Feature2D` is a subclass of) is implemented using the [PIMPL idiom](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pimpl) so that `SIFT` is actually a base/virtual class not intended to be instantiated directly; instead `SIFT::create` returns a `SIFT_Impl` instance, as you can see [in the code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/68d15fc62edad980f1ffa15ee478438335f39cc3/modules/features2d/src/sift.dispatch.cpp#L123-L139). The Python bindings can probably be "fixed" to mitigate this issue at some point in the future, but until then, you'll want to use `SIFT_create()`, `BRISK_create()`, and so on for all the feature detectors.

Note also that `SIFT.create()` and `BRISK.create()` and so on are valid generated names which are equivalent, but you'll find the underscore versions more common in tutorials and in people's projects, and they are currently the ones explicitly documented.